# How to copy MySQL function?

Tags: mysql, function

I have tried to use the export option in phpMyAdmin routines panel to copy functions from one database to another, with no success.

The export option supplies me with the following:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `JSON_FIELD_NUM`(`col_name` TEXT CHARSET utf8, `data` TEXT CHARSET utf8) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
    NO SQL
BEGIN
   RETURN 
   CONCAT('"',col_name,'":',
       IF(ISNULL(data),0,data)
   );
END
```

I get this error when I run that in another database:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7
```

I tried adding `DELIMITER $$` at the top and `$$` after `END`, but still no joy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set your client's statement delimiter to a string other than `;` in order that it doesn't think the semicolon which ends the `CONCAT()` expression also terminates the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement.

In the MySQL command line tool, you can use the `DELIMITER` [command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-commands.html).  In phpMyAdmin, you will need to use the `Delimiter` text box before clicking `Go`.

Comment: Delimiter text box ... so obvious once you know its there, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a far more concise way to do this:

```
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --routines"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --all-databases"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --no-data"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --no-create-info"
mysqldump ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} > StoredProcedures.sql
less StoredProcedures.sql
```

This will dump only Stored Procedures.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Surely this will produce the same `CREATE FUNCTION` statement as that with which the OP is already having problems?

Comment: @eggyal The `DELIMITER` statements are generated within the mysqldump

Comment: And the OP says he's already tried using `DELIMITER`.  The problem is that he's not using the MySQL command line tool.